# How to add MapView and other component in a LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have seen many related questions but I can not spot where I am doing it wrong. I appreciate if anyone can help me. When I add only one MapView to the LinearLayout, map is working fine. But when I try to add one button or textView or anything in the layout it crashes in run time!

I have three separate `fragments`. First one is called FragmentA.java and Fragment_a.xml

Here is Fragment_a.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
<Button android:id="@+id/googlemaps_select_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Select"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is

```
FragmentA.java
```

I am not sure if

```
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
```

is correct. fragment_a, as I said is the name of the fragment which contain complete view:

```
    public class FragmentA  extends Fragment {

            MapView mapView;
            GoogleMap map;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

                // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
                mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
                mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
                map = mapView.getMap();
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

                // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
                map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume() {
                mapView.onResume();
                super.onResume();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                mapView.onDestroy();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLowMemory() {
                super.onLowMemory();
                mapView.onLowMemory();
            }
}
```

I got the error which says, `inflate exception binary xml file line #10 error inflating class fragment.`

```
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164): Process: com.ass3.journeytracker, PID: 2164
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at com.ass3.journeytracker.FragmentA.onCreateView(FragmentA.java:33)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.maps.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ass3.journeytracker-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ass3.journeytracker-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164):     ... 43 more
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare sure just one second.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please have a look at update

Comment: Please copy and paste the **text** of the **entire** stack trace into your question.

Comment: What is on `line 33` in `FragmentA`?

Comment: @nem It is:    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a , container, false);

Comment: @nem the line that I am suspicious to and mentioned above

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class

Comment: @nem Do you know how can I reduce resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
09-22 14:43:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2164): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.maps.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ass3.journeytracker-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ass3.journeytracker-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

There is no `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in Maps V2. [The class name is `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html).