# Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, xml, textview

I am using Android Studio, when i use textview in my layout application is closing showing error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.SubFragment.onCreateView(SubFragment.java:20)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
```

and here in my Fragment class

```
public class SubFragment extends Fragment{


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homescreen, container, false);// getting error here


        return rootView;
    }


}
```

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/offers">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonOffers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/offers_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOffers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonOffers"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Offer"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

this code is working fine with eclipse. only problem when i try to work in Studio

Comment: can u pls post xml and all ?

Comment: double check your xml file, where you declare your textview, this means you have made a spelling mistake somewhere. Probably forgot a character or something.

Comment: @user1140237 added xml

Comment: @SboneloMbhamali, I tested this, the same code working in eclipse, i have postred my xml code for reference

Comment: you xml i checked its correct (considering root view is with correct namespace) once clean and build app(make project). or post the code for the fragment transaction related

Comment: Since your root layout is vertical, I dont think you need the layout_below attribute of your textview, try fixing that and see what happenss.

Comment: You are missing the **namespace** declaration. Add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
android:background="@drawable/offers"
```

i hope offers is image and its larger than the screen so replace by some color code n try

Like this

```
android:background="#ff0000"
```

hope it works..

check this too

[android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class)

**edit:**

remove this line

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

Comment: remove this `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"` n try

Comment: this answer helped for me

Comment: I solved the strange problem, when change the line ```android:textSize```, I put the value directly and not from dimens xml file. Like this: ```android:textSize="35sp"```

Comment: @ M S Gadag, What we have to do if " parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"> " this line is in styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your xml and added the namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/offers"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonOffers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/offers_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewOffers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Offer"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you are using a LinearLayout, parameters like "android:layout_below" or "android:layout_centerHorizontal" are not invalid.

Comment: first i tried with the Relative layout, so i have used layout_below params.. and this is a child of my main xml, so as of my knowledge, there is no need of adding namespace again for child

Comment: The, you should paste your entire xml layout. It's confusing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error.

I solved it by simply recreating new `.xml` file containing `TextView`.
In my case, the error was the xml version(v21\abc.xml).
code run well in android version 6(marshmallow) rather than it throws error while run in android version 4.4(kitkat).

Answer (score 1):

I was Faced with the same problem.
Make sure you Do not have 
            `tools:targetApi="lollipop"` in any of your Layouts.Instead, have two Layouts one under `layout`  add the other under `layout-v21` folder.

Comment: When I had this problem, all I did to fix it was remove the android:drawableLeft statement. It turns out that assigning an image to an AutoCompleteTextView on pre-Lollipop devices causes the problem. On my Lollipop phone, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems old versions of Android do not support tags like,

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
android:textSize="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
```

In that case, remove it from the XML file, and try to load the attributes from the Java or Kotlin code (preferably inside a try...catch or an if...else clause)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another .xml file in the res-> font folder of your project. After that call the font file in the .xml file.

```
<font
    android:font="@font/rubikbold"/>
```

Here, I have a robik bold font file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Check your theme parent. If mismatch happens between theme parent and style parent you get the attribute missing or failed to resolve error.
In my case I was using a theme of parent :

> Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar

But in my style I used parent as :

> TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small

Since they are different it causes failed to resolve symbol error.
Hope this might help..

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar error but I found out the attribute textAppearance was not properly written.

initially `android:textSize="?android:textAppearanceMedium"` instead of `android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"`

you can read more about TextView here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView