# Memory issue with my Android app

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

Hi my Android application is working fine on my Lenovo a319 device , in this device it consuming 40 MB of RAM meanwhile on the Galaxy s5 Device , it consuming 300 Mb for the same build(apk). And I am getting lot of errors such as memory issue on Galaxy s5 device.

For Instance

> Out of memory

exception and

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line

errors. I have found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class)  where it is answered that high pixel resolution will cause memory exception , I am not able to get any clue from that answers provided in that Question , kindly provide the support on the same?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers but they are inacurate i reuse recycle bitmaps and i make them null, even call system.gc(); and my memory is constant, i just do not understand that why it takes 300 MB of ram at sumasung galxy s5 and just 40 on my lenovo. My lenovo is hdpi s5 is xxhdpi if i am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing can be an easy fix for this

just add this line in your application tag in manifest file

`android:largeHeap="true"`

like this

`<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    ......`

and if you want to more optimize your code then use **Memory Analyser in eclipse**

Comment: better to fix your leaks? Like recycle bitmaps and stuff, largeHeap=true doesnt always help

Comment: yes i know its better to fix leaks, but sometimes there may be large images thats why largeheap is better solution i think sir

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your app was built using layouts defined in xml files. These layouts uses images like images for background or source images for `ImageButton` or `ImageView` etc. All your drawables are usually stored in `drawable-DENSITY` folders. So you need to lower resolution of all of your drawables to save some RAM. Like if you have some drawable for `ImageView` lets call it new_image.jpg and its in `drawable-hdpi` and its resolution is 800x600 px try to resize it to 400x300 px (you could use a Farstone Image Viewer for this). Do that with every drawable in project and see what happens.
Also it could be that you are displaying images in `ListViews` using some ImageLoader like Glide (recommended) or UIL or Picasso or whatever use use. Such loaders are usually consuming a lot of RAM (which is configurable however) for caching needs and due to that at one point AOS fails to load, build and represent some your layout which uses images by itself.
Also I recommend you [to lern how to display Bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) you **MUST** know such things.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from bitmaps and drawables the most common problem is leaking memory through the Activity context. Make sure that you are not passing around the activity to callback listeners.
A good tool to analyze memory is MAT(Memory Analyzer Tool). It helps you find out memory leaks in your app