# Why my android application is using much more memory on high end devices?

Tags: android, memory

Hi I have asked before [question relating memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490510/memory-issue-with-my-android-app). Since then I have allowed larger heap size, and i have created all the images in right resolution, but still i have an issue that the application is using from 150 to 230 MB of RAM on Samsung Galaxy S5, and the same app and the same build is using just 10-20 MB of RAM on Lenovo A319. What am I missing? Please explain me it. I am clearing the memory and recycling the images to, it was not an issue with the app earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the resolution difference in these two devices. when you set an image to a `ImageView` and assume it's full screen.

1. S5 scales it to 1080p so when the image convert to `BitMap` it would take 8.2944 Mb
2. In A319 (400X800) would use only 1.28Mb to show same image in full screen.

Devices which has high resolution comes with higher RAM's so if your app does not cause `OutOfMemoryException`'s you don't have to worry about this

Comment: Thanks For the explanation, my Senior analytic was complaining because of that issue, so I rather be sure before i say him that it is natural for android devices with higher resolution/dpi