# My HappyBirthday app force closes on my phone

Tags: android, debugging, forceclose

I am currently taking a free online course in Android and we are learning to make a simple output app. My app was working fine until today. I changed the images used in it and the background color of the TextViews, but that's about it. I don't know why the app will no longer run on my phone. (Note 3, Android 5.0 Stock ROM)

Here's my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/tanwood"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/congrats"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:paddingTop="75dp"
        android:paddingBottom="75dp"

        android:scaleType="centerInside"

        />

    <TextView android:text="Congratulations, Bro!!!"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        android:background="#D50000"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        />


    <TextView android:text="You are an official G! (graduate)"

        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        android:background="#D50000"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the logcat:

```
06-11 01:32:33.646  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
06-11 01:32:33.646  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday E/Zygote﹕ v2
06-11 01:32:33.646  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10254
06-11 01:32:33.646  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
06-11 01:32:33.676  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N900T_5.0_0002
06-11 01:32:33.676  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
06-11 01:32:33.676  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-11 01:32:33.756  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday D/ResourcesManager﹕ creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.example.justi.happybirthday-2/base.apk
06-11 01:32:33.766  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.example.justi.happybirthday can be debugged on port 8100...
06-11 01:32:34.586  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 58MB allocation
06-11 01:32:34.596  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 61382172 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 19MB until OOM"
06-11 01:32:34.596  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
06-11 01:32:34.596  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-11 01:32:34.596  15489-15489/com.example.justi.happybirthday E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.justi.happybirthday, PID: 15489
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.justi.happybirthday/com.example.justi.happybirthday.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.justi.happybirthday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.justi.happybirthday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 61382172 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3730)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:151)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.justi.happybirthday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

I truly appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have misnamed the id of the layout to be inflated

Comment: I think image bitmap is too large that way this problem happens you have to check out this : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class/23202156#23202156

Comment: Thanks so much you all! I reduced the size of the tanwood image by 50% and now the app runs fine. I have to study image size and memory. We haven't gone over that section yet =/

Answer (score 1):

It is an OutOfMemoryException as from logs -

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 61382172 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 19MB until OOM

I think you have used any/some large sized images (may be in MB) in your res folder.

Comment: Thanks so much! I reduced the size of the tanwood image by 50% and now the app runs fine. I have to study image size and memory. We haven't gone over that section yet =/