# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout

Tags: android, runtime-error

This error comes when I am running the app.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo :
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class android.widget.GridLayout

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ankur.shop.HomeActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:inAnimation="@color/abc_color_highlight_material"
        android:flipInterval="@integer/abc_config_activityDefaultDur">

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture4" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture5" />

    </ViewFlipper>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: can u post ur layout xml?

Comment: comment `tools:context="com.example.ankur.shop.HomeActivity"`

Comment: try it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class

Comment: Thanks Mr. Raghavendra

Comment: Can you post code of @drawable/gradient7? What device are you testing on (Android version)?

Comment: @Ankur did you solve the issue ? will you please let me know what was happened here ?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout),
you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view widget.

May be your `GridView` is not allowed where you are trying to use that. A RemoteViews object can support the following layout classes:

- FrameLayout
- LinearLayout
- RelativeLayout
- GridLayout

See more at [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

**Solution**

- Try using another layout type in your remote view.
- You probably using prior than 4.2. which may not support, review that too.