# Android Studio "Unfortunately my project has stopped" due to FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, emulation

When I run my project with the emulator, it popped up "Unfortunately project has stopped" with a fatal exception, can anyone look at my project and know what error is? I got following logcat error:

```
**03-07 18:42:53.990 2615-2615/com.example.admin.fragmentsmemecreator23 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.admin.fragmentsmemecreator23, PID: 2615
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.fragmentsmemecreator23/com.example.admin.fragmentsmemecreator23.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at com.example.admin.fragmentsmemecreator23.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.example.admin.fragmentsmemecreator23.BottomPictureFragment.onCreateView(BottomPictureFragment.java:19)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
    at com.example.admin.fragmentsmemecreator23.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
```

There are three java classes and three xml files: 1. MainActivity.java 2. TopSectionFragment.java 3. BottomPictureFragment.java 4. top_section_fragment.xml 5. bottom_picture_fragment.xml 6.activity_main.xml

1. MainActivity.java

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TopSectionFragment.TopSectionListener{

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       }

       //This gets called when the user clicks the button
       @Override
       public void createMeme(String top, String bottom) {
           BottomPictureFragment bottomFragment=(BottomPictureFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
           bottomFragment.setMemeText(top,bottom);

       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
           // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
           // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
           // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
           int id = item.getItemId();

           //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
           if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
               return true;
           }

           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
   ```
2. TopSectionFragment.java

   ```
   public class TopSectionFragment extends Fragment{
       private static EditText topTextInput;
       private static EditText bottomTextInput;

       TopSectionListener activityCommander;

       public interface TopSectionListener{
           public void createMeme(String top,String bottom);
       }

       @Override
       public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
           super.onAttach(activity);
           try {
               activityCommander = (TopSectionListener) activity;
           }catch (ClassCastException e){
               System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
               throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
           }
       }

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, container,false);
           topTextInput=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.topTextInput);
           bottomTextInput=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomTextInput);
           final Button button=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

           button.setOnClickListener(
                   new View.OnClickListener(){
                       public void onClick(View v){
                           buttonClicked(v);
                       }
                   }
           );
           return view;
       }

       public void buttonClicked(View view){
          activityCommander.createMeme(topTextInput.getText().toString(),bottomTextInput.getText().toString());
       }
   }
   ```
3. BottomPictureFragment.java

   ```
   public class BottomPictureFragment extends Fragment{
       private static TextView topMemeText;
       private static TextView bottomMemeText;

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_picture_fragment, container,false);
           topMemeText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.topMemeText);
           bottomMemeText=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomMemeText);

           return view;
       }

       public void setMemeText(String top,String bottom){
           topMemeText.setText(top);
           bottomMemeText.setText(bottom);
       }
   }
   ```
4. top_section_fragment.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/topTextInput"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           android:width="300dp"/>

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/bottomTextInput"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/topTextInput"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           android:width="300dp"/>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/bottomTextInput"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           android:text="@string/button_text"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
5. bottom_picture_fragment.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/chirag">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
           android:text="@string/top_text"
           android:id="@+id/topMemeText"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:textColor="#FFF"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
           android:text="@string/bottom_text"
           android:id="@+id/bottomMemeText"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:textColor="#FFF"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
6. activity_main.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       tools:context="com.example.admin.fragmentsmemecreator23.MainActivity">

       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
               app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202156/5795310) maybe can help you

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be , You should replace the activity with the fragment first and then pass arguments of top and bottom value to that fragment.

It would be something like

```
@Override
public void createMeme(String top, String bottom) 
        Fragment fragment = new BottomPictureFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("Top", top);
        args.putString("Bottom",bottom);
        fragment .setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment).commit();
```

After doing this you can get the arguments in the BottomPictureFragment inside onCreateView() and call the setMeme(top,bottom) function from the onCreateView().

Comment: `Fragment fragment = new BottomPictureFragment();` should be `BottomPictureFragment fragment = new BottomPictureFragment()

Comment: and also in last line of code in  `.replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment)` activity_main is not an id it is a layout. I tried changing it to layout but it won't work. Sir can you please all the code changes. And why should I call a setter function onCreateView(). I am just a beginner in android programming. I will be grateful to you. Thank You.

Comment: Sorry I just solved the problem. problem was with the image. I used smaller image and it worked.