# unfortunately app has stopped in android emulator when imageview loaded

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

i am developing a small android application and i am using Imageview to load some images to the application

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/starr"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Ishan ayesha"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small TextSmall TextSmall TextSmall TextSmall TextSmall TextSmall Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />
```

now when i run this using my phone it crashes the app and stopping working.But when i run this on my computer simulator it works fine.what is the reason for this

in the log cat i am getting error

```
03-12 01:38:07.250 23317-23317/com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania, PID: 23317
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania/com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2319)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                                         at com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5296)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020057 a=-1 r=0x7f020057}
                                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3420)
                                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:603)
                                                                                         at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:134)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
                                                                                         at com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5296) 
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

03-12 01:38:27.780 23317-23317/com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23317 SIG: 9

Comment: If you could add the associated activity or fragment, as well as a stack trace, it would be easier to diagnose.

Comment: I think its going out of memory, can you please post some logs?

Comment: Can you read the Logcat? what was the error. And what kind of device are you using? is there any library you're using to fetch images?

Comment: well i have  added the log cat to the post again see the updated

Comment: @SalvatoryBaya  
well i have added the log cat to the post again see the updated

Comment: it looks like there is a problem on the xml file inflating the image view. and my suspect is the src.

Comment: @pavithra take a look at `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020057 a=-1 r=0x7f020057}` Does the drawable exist?

Comment: @hoomi yeah the drawable is exist

Comment: What is you drawable? if it is an xml please put the code as well

Comment: @hoomi no drawable is an image

Comment: what type of image is it? (png,jpg,...) Also just to see if it is because of image replace it with some other image (app icon for example) and see if the crash continues

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search on this issue, I learned the following:

- Inflateexception is most likely not the actual problem.
- It could be an out of memory exception.
- Verify the pixel resolution for your images. The higher the resolution, the more likely it is to cause a problem. Try to keep the resolution at the minimum.

So check the pixel resolution, try messing around with it to a point where we can still see the image but isn't too taxing on the memory for operations.

Resource:

- [StackOverflow: android.view.InflateException Ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class)