# Logcat Error Run time Exception, unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, logcat

I was wondering why that when I tried running the application in  the emulator. The app stopped working. I was hoping what was the reason of my run time exception.

This is the copy of my full logcat:

```
04-14 02:40:39.904 6836-6836/com.example.jas.emojiexpress E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jas.emojiexpress, PID: 6836
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jas.emojiexpress/com.example.jas.emojiexpress.HomePage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.example.jas.emojiexpress.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:18)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.example.jas.emojiexpress.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:18) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.example.jas.emojiexpress.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:18) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.example.jas.emojiexpress.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:18) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my HomePage java:

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, ChoicePage.class));
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Here is content of my homepage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_page"
tools:context=".HomePage"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundnew">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="332dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="332dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:background="#FFB6C1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="   Click This   "
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your `LinearLayout`s are nested and indented abnormally. The first `LinearLayout` nested within the parent contains nothing, and the second one contains a button, but the indentations make it look different. Try removing the first nested `LinearLayout`, although I doubt that's your issue.

Comment: Can you post xml of ChoicePage.class

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` - Looks like the background image you're using for the root `LinearLayout` in `HomePage`'s layout is too big.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612
>   byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM

If you examine the `Caused by:` lines, it looks like the root cause is an `OutOfMemoryError` that's occurring in `BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset()`. (Note also the references to "Out of memory on a 74649612-byte allocation").

Are you trying to include a very large image file in your layout somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be because your `@drawable/backgroundnew` has too high a pixel resolution. Someone reported a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class).

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you have defined them with AppCompat because here you extended AppCompatActivity, so if you have not defined please define and try they me solve your crash, Like below.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```