# Error inflating class RadioButton

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button

I am creating quiz app using php mysql json parsor, In that ran the program it shows "`Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class RadioButton`" the error on create xml file. 
I am using these codes in `QuizActivity.java` crash log will throw the error on create content vie and layout inflater

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView quizQuestion;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton optionOne;
private RadioButton optionTwo;
private RadioButton optionThree;
private RadioButton optionFour;
private int currentQuizQuestion;
private int quizCount;
private QuizWrapper firstQuestion;
private List<QuizWrapper> parsedObject;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
   // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);    quizQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    optionOne = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    optionTwo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    optionThree = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    optionFour = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    Button previousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousquiz);
    Button nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextquiz);
    AsyncJsonObject asyncObject = new AsyncJsonObject();
    asyncObject.execute("");
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
       {
            int radioSelected = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int userSelection = getSelectedAnswer(radioSelected);
            int correctAnswerForQuestion = firstQuestion.getCorrectAnswer();
            if(userSelection == correctAnswerForQuestion){
                // correct answer
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "You got the answer correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                currentQuizQuestion++;
                if(currentQuizQuestion >= quizCount){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "End of the Quiz Questions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);
                    quizQuestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
                    String[] possibleAnswers = firstQuestion.getAnswers().split(",");
                    uncheckedRadioButton();
                    optionOne.setText(possibleAnswers[0]);
                    optionTwo.setText(possibleAnswers[1]);
                    optionThree.setText(possibleAnswers[2]);
                    optionFour.setText(possibleAnswers[3]);
                }
            }
            else{
                // failed question
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "You chose the wrong answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentQuizQuestion--;
            if(currentQuizQuestion < 0){
                return;
            }
            uncheckedRadioButton();
            firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);
            quizQuestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
            String[] possibleAnswers = firstQuestion.getAnswers().split(",");
            optionOne.setText(possibleAnswers[0]);
            optionTwo.setText(possibleAnswers[1]);
            optionThree.setText(possibleAnswers[2]);
            optionFour.setText(possibleAnswers[3]);
        }
    });
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".QuizActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question"
    android:id="@+id/quiz_question"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quiz_question"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/quiz_question"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/quiz_question"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_bg"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_bg"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_bg"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_bg"
        android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/nextquiz"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/next_questions"
    android:background="@drawable/quizbutton"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/previousquiz"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/previousquiz"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/previous_questions"
    android:background="@drawable/quizbutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioGroup" />
```

```
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class RadioButton
```

Comment: please add crash log

Comment: don´t use `@+id` except you want to give a new `id`. for all other references to views, only do `@id` . But I don´t think that causes this error....

Comment: and if you have made earlier changes, clean your project....

Comment: May be your `radio_bg` is of high resolution, watch it... Rest of the codes are fine.

Comment: is this post from your xml code the exact code?

Comment: Yes this is exact xml code

Comment: @GnanaPrakash did u find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed orientation attribute in `<RadioGroup>` element. Try,

```
android:orientation = "vertical"
```

inside your <`RadioGroup>` element and then try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I tried to use of this "android:orientation = "vertical" " but nothing change

Comment: I have run your code and it is working perfectly. May be the problem is with selector you have specified with button attribute. Make sure your selector is correct. Otherwise there is no issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46646047/6632278

If you have created the file radio_bg in v24/drawable you must copy in drawable too for support to android devices before version 7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while setting custom radio icons in line:

```
android:button="@drawable/radio_bg"
```

Because I mistakenly pasted `radio_bg.xml` or vice versa In `drawable-v24`  and the error was only in older versions. so pasting same `radio_bg.xml` in common `drawable` folder fixed the problem.