# application stops showing error in Toast message

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview, layout-inflater, android-toast

Suddenly my application crashing while displaying Toast message.
It was working perfectly before.

I have fragment with `ImageView` and button download that image. I show the image by downloading in temporary location and show in `imageview`. If user clicks on save image, i simply rename the temporary file.

I remember I have not touched this fragment code and layout and related classes but was modifying other file and updated `gradle` and android studio to latest 2.1. 
Suddenly my app is stopping with exceptions and below is the `logcat` which i couldn't understand.

Also some other places where toast message were displaying now getting errors.

I am referring to the link
[android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class)

but not sure what step i should take to resolve this strange error.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:262)
at com.srids.sathyasaiinspires.FragmentImage$1.onClick(FragmentImage.java:78)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:262) 
at com.srids.sathyasaiinspires.FragmentImage$1.onClick(FragmentImage.java:78) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
at android.content.res.Resources.toPreloadCookie(Resources.java:2491)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2519)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3813)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:498)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:200)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:196)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:192)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:262)
```

My updated gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
```

Below is the xml file of the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        style="@style/btnStyleSandrift"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_sandrift"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/cont_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/default_image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/btnStyleSandrift"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_sandrift"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/SaveImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

FragmentImage.java file Code just implements onCreateView() as shown below:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
   loader = R.drawable.default_image;
   imgview = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

   urlImageString = getArguments().getString("URLIMAGESTRING");
   file_string = getArguments().getString("FILESTRING");

   imgLoader = new ImageLoader(super.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
   imgLoader.DisplayImage(urlImageString, loader, imgview, file_string);

   Button imgBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if (imgLoader.SaveImage(file_string)) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Image saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Image not found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   });
   return rootView;
}
```

when app is started on portrait mode and if i click on save it is crashing. before that If i rotate, that loads land\fragment_image.xml with same image and button simply works. Again after putting portrait mode, there is no crash.
This is happening in my xperia Z only. on Emulators, it is working perfectly.

**Fix identified:**

Took me almost 3 days to see what is causing the issue and finally the issue seems in appcompat-v7-23.2.1
I replaced my support libraries as below and everything is working fine.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

And I referred below link also:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201817

Comment: Catch `InvocationTargetException` and show log using `getCause()` method.

Comment: Actually it was caused by `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, show your code instead.

Comment: there is something wrong in your `xml` please check it or update your question including the layout of that fragment

Comment: let us know your code to look into

Comment: Please show your `FragmentImage.java` class, not a long explanation of a problem

Comment: any help on this? I tried all ways but not able to figure out why this is crashing always.