# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android. I am getting the error as android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class . Earlier this activity was running fine. But suddenly getting this error. Cleaned the project so many times. But didn't work. My exception is :

```
06-06 10:00:39.255: E/ActivityThread(12779): RuntimeExceptionjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

XML layout is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.88"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.88" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonCat"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="68dp"
                    android:text="@string/SViewAll" />

                <org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.Tutorial3View
                    android:id="@+id/tutorial3_activity_java_surface_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.88" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/lightbulb" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewState"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/SIdle"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_green" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_yellow" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_red" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.07"
                android:text="@string/STrain"
                android:textOff="@string/STrain"
                android:textOn="@string/SStopTrain" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.71"
                android:text="@string/SFaceName"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.76"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonBuscar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/SSearch"
                android:textOff="@string/SSearch"
                android:textOn="@string/SStopSearch" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButtonGrabar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Grabar"
                android:textOff="Rec"
                android:textOn="Stop" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.73"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_stat_camera" />

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I got error in xml layout :

```
org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.Tutorial3View failed to instantiate.
```

The exception stack trace is :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.R$styleable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.<init>(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:67)
    at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.<init>(JavaCameraView.java:65)
    at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.Tutorial3View.<init>(Tutorial3View.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3028)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

The code of Tutorial3View is :

```
public class Tutorial3View extends JavaCameraView {

    private static final String TAG = "Sample::Tutorial3View";

    public Tutorial3View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }


    public List<String> getEffectList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
    }

    public boolean isEffectSupported() {
        return (mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect() != null);
    }

    public String getEffect() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect();
    }

    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setColorEffect(effect);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }

    public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }

    public void setResolution(Size resolution) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = resolution.height;
        mMaxWidth = resolution.width;
        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public void setResolution(int w,int h) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = h;
        mMaxWidth = w;

        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public void setAutofocus()
    {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
//       if (parameters.isVideoStabilizationSupported())
//         {
//             parameters.setVideoStabilization(true);
//         }
         mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    }
    public void setCamFront()
    {
         disconnectCamera();
        // setCameraIndex(org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT );
         connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    public void setCamBack()
    {
         disconnectCamera();         
        // setCameraIndex(org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK );
         connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public int numberCameras()
    {
     return Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    }

    public Size getResolution() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    }

    public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Tacking picture");
        PictureCallback callback = new PictureCallback() {

            private String mPictureFileName = fileName;

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
                Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
                    picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    picture.recycle();
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, callback);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this exception ? Any advice is of great help .

Comment: If you are Using Weight  in layout then height/width must be 0dp

Comment: Can u post the package of Tutorial3View?

Comment: The code of org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.Tutorial3View is given .

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202156/6097062

Comment: I have seen that . That answer does not solve my exception

Comment: @SagorAhmed but first line is not there "package". Please post that or Can u do one thing? Press and hold ctrl and click Tutorial3View in that xml and check whether its leading Tutorial3View class or not?

Comment: You are getting a `ClassNotFoundException` - did you add `opencv` dependencies or library?

Comment: I have added opencv library .