# Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-resources, android-inflate

I build my app against

```
minSdkVersion 11
targetSdkVersion 23
```

When I run it on Samsug Galaxy S5 or Note5, the app runs fine with no problem. But when I try to run it on a Samsung S3 running android 4.4.2, it crashes with the following stack trace. I already read [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class). Does my stack trace shed some particular light so that someone can help me further?

Also the reference to line `153` in MainActivity is simply `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

And all my themes are `AppCompat` such as `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.business.android, PID: 24152
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.business.android/com.business.android.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class ImageView
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class ImageView
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
  at com.business.android.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:153)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/sel_touch_feedback.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020081
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3066)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3701)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
  at com.business.android.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:153) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
         Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:181)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3062)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3701) 
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127) 
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57) 
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039) 
  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
  at com.business.android.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:153) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE**

(Thanks Machinarius) Here is the drawable file that may be causing the problem. Any ideas how I might fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccentLight" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccentLight" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!--<item android:color="@color/white"></item>-->
</selector>
```

Comment: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable. Have you looked into this? Seems like the problematic file is res/drawable/sel_touch_feedback.xml

Comment: I have edited to show the drawable in question. Any ideas how I might fix it?

Comment: That file should be in `res/color`... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: Thanks! I just took out that file entirely and used `?attr/colorControlHighlight` and the crash went away!!!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to comments by Machinarius and cricket_007 I was able to zero in on the problem. In the end I just removed the problem drawable, which I was creating on the fly through xml, and just used `?attr/colorControlHighlight` everywhere I was using that drawable.

The drawable in question was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccentLight" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccentLight" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!--<item android:color="@color/white"></item>-->
</selector>
```

It turns out I didn't need it after all.