# Second time I swipe to a Fragment it crashes

Tags: java, android

I am using a viewpager to swipe between three different fragments and the third one is a MapFragment. The application loads fine the first time but crashes when I swipe back to the first fragment a second time.

Here is the layout for my first fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.nihardalal.tabview.Fragments.OneFragment"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResponse"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40px"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Find Me"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code for my fragment class is as follows:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
private String text;
buttonClicker mCallback;

public OneFragment() {

}

public interface buttonClicker {
    public void onButtonClicked();
}

@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (buttonClicker) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancesState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
    txt.setText(MainActivity.response1);
    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                   mCallback.onButtonClicked();
                               }
                           }
    );
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

}
```

The layout of three fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.nihardalal.tabview.Fragments.ThreeFragment"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code for three fragment:

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private String address;
    public ThreeFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
        mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        this.address = args.getString("address");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map){
        GoogleMap mMap = map;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera new LatLng(18.94102, 72.82427)
        LatLng place = new LatLng(18.94102, 72.82427);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place).title("Marker at Al-sabah"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, 17));
    }

    public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress) {

        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
        List<Address> address;
        LatLng p1 = null;

        try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
            if (address == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return p1;
    }
}
```

The main activity is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OneFragment.buttonClicker{
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private String jsonResponse;
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;
    private OnMapReadyCallback mapReadyCallback;
    public static String response1, response2;
    private String address;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        makeJsonArrayRequest();
//        mMapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
//        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("data.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }

    private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("info");

            for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
                jsonResponse = "";
                JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("name"));
                JSONObject phone = jo_inside.getJSONObject("phone");
                jsonResponse += "Name: " + jo_inside.getString("name") + "\n\n";
                jsonResponse += "Email: " + jo_inside.getString("email") + "\n\n";
                jsonResponse += "Home: " + phone.getString("home") + "\n\n";
                jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + phone.getString("mobile") + "\n\n";
                jsonResponse += "Address: " + jo_inside.getString("address") + "\n\n\n";

                if (i == 0) {
                    address = jo_inside.getString("address");
                    MainActivity.response1 = jsonResponse;
                } else {
                    MainActivity.response2 = jsonResponse;
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Fragment oneFragment = new OneFragment();
        Bundle oneArgs = new Bundle();
        oneArgs.putString("text", response1);
        oneFragment.setArguments(oneArgs);
        Fragment twoFragment = new TwoFragment();
        Bundle twoArgs = new Bundle();
        twoArgs.putString("text", response2);
        twoFragment.setArguments(twoArgs);
        Fragment threeFragment = new ThreeFragment();
        Bundle threeArgs = new Bundle();
        threeArgs.putString("address", address);
        adapter.addFragment(oneFragment, "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(twoFragment, "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(threeFragment, "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void onButtonClicked() {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nihardalal.tabview, PID: 2867
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at com.example.nihardalal.tabview.Fragments.ThreeFragment.onCreateView(ThreeFragment.java:47)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1430)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:728)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:254)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at com.example.nihardalal.tabview.Fragments.ThreeFragment.onCreateView(ThreeFragment.java:47) 
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1430) 
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:728) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:254) 
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603) 
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f0d00a1, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2293)
     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at com.example.nihardalal.tabview.Fragments.ThreeFragment.onCreateView(ThreeFragment.java:47) 
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1430) 
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:728) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025) 
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:254) 
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603) 
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I'm an Android newbie and I'm just trying to learn how to use GoogleMaps and a ViewPager. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class

Comment: What is the layout of `ThreeFragment`