# Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class ImageButton onload but only on some devices

Tags: android, android-appcompat, imagebutton, inflate-exception

I am getting this error:

```
Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class ImageButton
```

I just dont understand why. It only happens on some devices, not all. On the same emulator its working with api 21, but when using api 19 it just crashes. I tried to find solutions like updating tools, removing libraries and stuff like that but it didnt work. How can I fix this?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.company.example, PID: 24772
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.example/com.company.example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class ImageButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class ImageButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.company.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020088 a=-1 r=0x7f020088}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2073)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:57)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at com.company.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My activity_main.xml a.k.a. my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.company.example.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:id="@+id/view">
<include
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
app:tabMode="fixed"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorWhite"
></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
android:layout_below="@+id/view"
></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:visibility="gone"
fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/colorWhite"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/MyRandomTheme"
fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_today_24dp"
fab:fab_size="mini"
fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimary"
android:onClick="getWeek"/>

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_person_24dp"
fab:fab_size="mini"
android:onClick="getLeerling"/>

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_settings_24dp"
fab:fab_size="mini"
android:onClick="getSettings"/>

</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
android:src="@drawable/ic_cached_white_24dp"
android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:onClick="restartApp"/><!--32 dp bottom-->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity is too big to post, so well ... eh ... ill post the oncreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //setTheme(R.style.MyRandomTheme);
    main = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent().hasExtra(getPackageName())){notificationManager.cancelAll(); }
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ToolbarIconsTextview);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    if (width <= 520) {title.setTextSize(14);}
    final SharedPreferences prefers = this.getSharedPreferences("com.devwild.zermelo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //prefers.edit().putBoolean("premium", false).apply();
    int PrimaryColor = prefers.getInt("PrimaryColor", 0);
    final TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    FloatingActionButton Fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    if (PrimaryColor != 0) {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(PrimaryColor));
        tablayout.setBackgroundColor(PrimaryColor);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(CircleView.shiftColorDown(PrimaryColor));
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(PrimaryColor);
            ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription("Zermelo", null, PrimaryColor); //replace icon today with zermelo
            (this).setTaskDescription(taskDescription);
        }
        Fab.setRippleColor(PrimaryColor);
        Fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(PrimaryColor));
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 17) {
        try {
            FloatingActionsMenu multiple_actions = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions);
            multiple_actions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            GridLayout toolBar = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.ToolbarIcons);
            toolBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView toolbarIconsTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ToolbarIconsTextview);
            toolbarIconsTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.devwild.zermelo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String authcode = prefs.getString("Authcode", "");
    String school = prefs.getString("School", "");
    if (authcode.equalsIgnoreCase(null) || authcode.equalsIgnoreCase("") || school.equalsIgnoreCase(null) || school.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new LoginFragment(), "VR");
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        GridLayout toolBar = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.ToolbarIcons);
        toolBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TextView toolbarIconsTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ToolbarIconsTextview);
        toolbarIconsTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Maandag(), "MA");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Dinsdag(), "DI");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Woensdag(), "WO");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Donderdag(), "DO");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Vrijdag(), "VR");
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, LICENSE_KEY, MERCHANT_ID, new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
            prefers.edit().putBoolean("premium", true).apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aankoop voltooid! Enorm bedankt! Geniet van de app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {}
        @Override
        public void onBillingInitialized() {
            if (prefers.contains("premium")) {
                if (prefers.getBoolean("premium", false) == true) {}
                else {
                    bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
                    boolean isItPurchased = bp.isPurchased("premium");
                    if (isItPurchased == true) {prefers.edit().putBoolean("premium", true).apply();}
                }
            }
            else {
                bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
                boolean isItPurchased = bp.isPurchased("premium");
                if (isItPurchased == true) {prefers.edit().putBoolean("premium", true).apply();}
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {}
    });

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent().hasExtra(getPackageName())){notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);}
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    Boolean notifications = prefs.getBoolean("Notificaties", false);
    if (prefs.contains("Notificaties")) {
        if (notifications == true) {
            switch (currentDay) {
                case 1:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
                case 2:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);prefers.edit().putString("NotificationDay", "Monday").apply();notificationThread.start();break;
                case 3:viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);prefers.edit().putString("NotificationDay", "Tuesday").apply();notificationThread.start();break;
                case 4:viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);prefers.edit().putString("NotificationDay", "Wednesday").apply();notificationThread.start();break;
                case 5:viewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);prefers.edit().putString("NotificationDay", "Thursday").apply();notificationThread.start();break;
                case 6:viewPager.setCurrentItem(4, true);prefers.edit().putString("NotificationDay", "Friday").apply();notificationThread.start();break;
                case 7:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
                default:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
            }
        }
        else {
            switch (currentDay) {
                case 1:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
                case 2:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
                case 3:viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);break;
                case 4:viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);break;
                case 5:viewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);break;
                case 6:viewPager.setCurrentItem(4, true);break;
                case 7:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
                default:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        switch (currentDay) {
            case 1:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
            case 2:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
            case 3:viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);break;
            case 4:viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);break;
            case 5:viewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);break;
            case 6:viewPager.setCurrentItem(4, true);break;
            case 7:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
            default:viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);break;
        }
    }

    if (prefs.contains("CompletedIntro")) {
        if (prefs.getBoolean("CompletedIntro", false)) {
        }
        else {
            finish();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Intro.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
    else if (!prefs.contains("CompletedIntro")) {
        finish();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Intro.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of vector drawable(svg)?

Comment: Is the image for your image button in a versioned folder? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class

Comment: @AdamForbis I don't know why there should be an image button. I never made one, and when I searched the whole project it was never really used, so its a bit stranged.

Comment: You may need to post the code for your activity, according to the logcat you have an ImageButton.

Comment: Your layout xml would also be useful.

Comment: @AdamForbis added!

Comment: Your error is actually ... `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):`

Comment: Is it possible to add just the onCreate() function?

Comment: It looks to be a problem with one of the floating actions buttons, I would try commenting some out and see if it improves things.

Comment: @AdamForbis I thought of that too, so I commented it out, but that didn't solve it unfortunaly :(

Comment: did the logcat change?, You might just comment out literally everything, then start putting them back in slowly

Comment: @AdamForbis thanks, I will try tomorrow! It's 11pm here :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117759/discussion-between-adam-forbis-and-jason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearantly, an icon in the toolbar that I include in the activity_main.xml was corrupt

Answer (score 1):

To clear the question where the ImageButton is coming from:

The `FloatingActionButton` class is extending `ImageButton` class.

---

The error is the following:

**Resource is not a Drawable**.

So somewhere in one of your `FloatingActionButton`s you used a drawable that contains errors or is not actually an image.

Check that.

Comment: It had nothing to do with the FloatingActionButton