# when i click on ImageView the App stop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

In my App , I'm trying to add some `ImageView` (`play2_one and play2_two`) and it navigates to another `Activity` after click in that `ImageView`. It works normally in **NEXUS S(API 25)** but not in **NOTE 3, NEXUS 5(API 24).**

What can be the issue? Please guide:

This is my logcat:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5727)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:352)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2058)
>                                                                                       at com.example.compassapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5581)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)

and this's my xml code :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bitmap">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play1_one"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/four" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play1_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/three" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/qiblaFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/frameImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/amer" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/compassImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/nnn" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and this Mainactivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    // define the display assembly compass picture
    private ImageView image1;

    // record the compass picture angle turned
    private float currentDegree = 0f;

    // device sensor manager
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    private TextView tvHeading1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // our compass image
        image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compassImage);

        // TextView that will tell the user what degree is he heading
        tvHeading1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
        // initialize your android device sensor capabilities
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play1_one);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CompassThree.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play1_two);
        imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Compasstwo.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        imageView1.setClickable(true);
        imageView2.setClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // for the system's orientation sensor registered listeners
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // to stop the listener and save battery
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // not in use
    }


}
```

Comment: what error u r getting can u share the logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: please post your log file and the corresponding  class file.

Comment: Where ? I did not get. @DesignMan

Comment: post yoyr xml file and java file.

Comment: See this answer first : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202156/5476209

Comment: Post your xml for compassone and compass I two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have added so many drawable in your layout, There can be an issue with memory on many devices, As you have said that  It works normally in **NEXUS S(API 25)** but not in **NOTE 3, NEXUS 5(API 24)**.

If there is a problem with Id or something else then it will not work on any device, So most probably it can be a memory issue.

You can increase memory heap size, See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application).

Also, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class/23202156#23202156) there also describe a similar problem.