# Android binary layout inflate exception : ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.layout" on path:

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                    android:layout_width="96dp"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/user_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@color/contentDividerLine" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_view">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@color/contentDividerLine" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Email"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/settings_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/settings_title"
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Settings"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/settings_title"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@color/contentDividerLine" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/settings_header">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/notification_pref"
                            app:label="@{@string/show_bounds}" />

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/location_pref"
                            app:label="@{@string/show_offsets}" />

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/sync_pref"
                            app:label="@{@string/show_bounds}" />

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/analytics_pref"
                            app:label="@{@string/show_offsets}" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </ScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Exception

```
01-05 18:17:15.102 10834-10834/com.creativemoments.unipoint E/CustomActivityOnCrash: 
    App has crashed, executing CustomActivityOnCrash's UncaughtExceptionHandler
                                                                                 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.creativemoments.unipoint/com.creativemoments.unipoint.profile.ProfileActivity}:
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
at com.creativemoments.unipoint.profile.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:28)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6001)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.creativemoments.unipoint-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
at com.creativemoments.unipoint.profile.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:28) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6001) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.layout
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: maybe this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class

Comment: Can you try with remove ` xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` line ?

Comment: have you checked path for de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView ? this may produce this error if you don't have imported successfully.

Comment: Clear project and rebuild and then run project

Comment: @MaxExplode Did you solve this issue? Please post your own answer or accept the one that worked for you.

Answer (score 34):

When I added in `build.gradle` it worked for me so you can try.

```
android {
    //...
     dataBinding {
            enabled = true 
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a reference from documentation or explain what this code does, how it solves the problem.

Comment: perfect answer!

Comment: Note: You must configure data binding for app modules that depend on libraries that use data binding, even if the app module doesn't directly use data binding.

@Cray this note comes from this documentation page https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start

Answer (score 9):

The error is specified as:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:
>   Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class layout Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class layout Caused by: java.lang.**ClassNotFoundException:**
>   **Didn't find class "android.view.layout" on path:**

**This error is caused when you have implemented data binding in your application.** In this case the user is using data binding (see inside the specified value of `app:label=`):

```xml
                        ...
                        <include
                            layout="@layout/notification_pref"
                            app:label="@{@string/show_bounds}" />

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/location_pref"
                            app:label="@{@string/show_offsets}" />

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/sync_pref"
                            app:label="@{@string/show_bounds}" />

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/analytics_pref"
                            app:label="@{@string/show_offsets}" />
                         ...
```

So we need to add into our `/app/build.gradle` file  the block `dataBinding`, to enable their use in our application.

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Another way to resolve this is by locating the layout that was included and removing the  tag since dataBinding is not enabled in the project.

see [Data binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start)

Answer (score 1):

This problem definitely has something to do with invalid xml.
In order to troubleshoot, make sure that all elements in the xml file can be found.
You can verify this by ctrl (or cmd) - clicking all layout items. 
Issues can arise when you for example don't use the correct namespace for compat elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

the xml namespace must be:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

So, edit your linear layout as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

....

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, make sure that you hav added this gradle dependency to your app's module:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no one particular cause of this problem.
I tried implementing all the solution posted above.

For me the problem is the way i included layout

```
<include layout="@layout/feed_fail_layout" />
```

Basically I bring everything included in feed_fail_layout to the main layout.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this exception is because you are trying to use a view that was not inflated.

In the case of using **[Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)**, it happened to me that I was trying to navigate to the destination of a view that at no time was inflated *(whether or not with DI)* within the activity. Therefore, make sure that you do not have  actions not allowed inside the activity in the `nav_graph`

GL

Answer (score 0):

It's because system tries to find the proper root layout element and it gets the `layout` element as a root and throws the error **if you are not using any binding library.**

**Solution**
In your content view xml file, cross check that you have correct **root layout**. If it is set as a `layout` then replace it with `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` or anything you are convenient with.
Also make sure your `setContentView` method setup correctly.

**If you are using binding library**, use below method in your app level `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    //...
     dataBinding {
            enabled = true 
     }
}
```