# Failed to inflate ImageView error

Tags: android, imageview, selector

My app can run on android 4 devices but when I change minSdkVersion from 25 to 16 I got following error:

```
...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
...
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView
...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/tab_btn.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020066
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tab_btn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Selector xml(tab_btn.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_btn_selected" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_btn_deselected" />
</selector>
```

Does android 4 support multistate imageViews?

Comment: Is changing from `app:srcCompat` to `android:src` fixing that behavior?

Comment: Or — even better — using `AppCompatImageView` instead.

Comment: nope, with `android:src` the error still there

Comment: Are you using vector images?

Comment: I think this post is related to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class . Probably you have to check the pixel resolution in your drawables images are just the minimum necessary for your layout.

Comment: @Michael:using `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` throws
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.AppCompatImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.rhyboo.com.selectortest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/net.rhyboo.com.selectortest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`
@DevKRos:Yes I'm using vector drawables and I'm sure they're fine since they run ok on api level 25

Comment: @undefined check my answer .Let me know if it works

Comment: @DevKRos a) Again I can run my test project just by changing minSdkVersion from 16 to 23 so resources are fine.b) using `app:src` instead of `app:srcCompat` produces parsing error `Unexpected namespace prefix app found for tag ImageView`

Comment: use android:src instead of app:src

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand that your device app is android 4 but you run it with minSdkVersion 25 ??

Comment: @undefined Okay i find two possible workaround 1>You make convert webp image fro  m vector  2> Use Selectors programatically and set images by using ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.tab_btn);

Answer (score 1):

Use android:src="@drawable/tab_btn" instead of app:srcCompat

Once that is done, Clean or invalidate cache and restart the project and run it. Sometimes resource Id's will not be refreshed.

Comment: there is no `src` attribute in the `app` namespace it belongs to `android` namespace

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you really using vector? If you're not using vector, consider to use `android:src`.

> For AppCompat users, we’ve decided to remove the functionality which let you use vector drawables from resources on pre-Lollipop devices due to issues found in the implementation in version 23.2.0/23.2.1. Using app:srcCompat and setImageResource() continues to work.

So, by right android version lower than lollipop cannot use this feature (only for vector). So you might need to set `minSdkVersion` to 23 instead of 16. You can refer to [AndroidDevelopers](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne) for this.

2) If you are not using vector and you still getting the error, probably you misplaced the file. Here is the hint:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Which folder did you put `tab_btn.xml`?. You need to ensure that the file is in drawable folder then use  `android:src="@drawable/tab_btn"` instead `app:srcCompat="@drawable/tab_btn"`.

Comment: Its vector drawable and its in the drawable foldder.Once again the project runs ok on  android 5+.I can't set minSdkVersion to 23 as my aim to make support of android 4 devices

Answer (score 0):

USE background:

```
       android:background="@drawable/tab_btn" 
instead     
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/tab_btn"
```

Or USE

```
    android:src
```

Comment: downvoting without explaining ? This is sure shot working code

Comment: `android:background` throws same error but with some new info: `Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector`

Comment: You sure u used namespace android instead of app: just as android:src ?instead of app:src

Comment: I think you are using vector drawble if yes then they must needed to be backward compatible have a look at here
  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html
  So in order to make it backward compatible please use  vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Comment: Yes I mentioned I'm using vector drawables above and I already have useSupportLibrary=true in the build.gradle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142064/discussion-between-devkros-and-undefined).

Comment: I am using png but still getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing all selectors from `ImageViews` plus `myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);`
Special thanks to @DevKRos

Answer (score 0):

If you would like use selector for view with VectorDrawables you need to add this:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

to every Activity where you want to use VectorDrawables on devices with versions below Android 5.
Without selector you could use:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/some_vector_drawable_without_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
`android:src="@drawable/app_logo"`

and still if it crashing then check out your drawable image is **not in drawable-v24** folder,

move your image to **drawable** folder. (mostly we need to do this if image is large in size or high resolution image)

**note**: Set ic_launcher image as src and if it works then problem is in your image. May be it large in size or high resolution.

hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a drawable file and before it was inside of drawable-24 folder, I just moved it to drawable folder and inside my gradled I added:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
```

And I used:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_picture"
```

Answer (score -2):

**A.** Make sure `tab_btn.xml`, `tab_btn_deselected` and `tab_btn_deselected` are exist in your `res/drawable/` folder.

**B.** Use attribute `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`

**Try this:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/tab_btn" />
```

Comment: To whom it may concern, may I know the reason of down-vote?

Comment: I think its due to this code won't compile as there is no src attribute in the app namespace.PS:it's not me who downvoted you

Comment: Ohh my mistake. It should be android:src