# Android app doesn't start in some phones

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, tic-tac-toe

I make a basic TicTacToe game. It's works perfectly on Nexus 5X 1920x1080(Emulator), Pixel XL 1440x2560 (Emulator), Xiaomi Mi5 1920x1080(My phone) but app doesn't opening on Samsung S7 edge 1440x2560(My phone), Meizu MX4 (1152x1920). I try everything. Android Studio doesn't show any error.

Also I try Appetize.io emulator for test and It work's on there too. Please help me I can't found problem.

```
**Log**

    01-25 07:46:04.892 29294-29294/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-25 07:46:04.920 29294-29294/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
01-25 07:46:05.388 29294-29294/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-25 07:46:05.773 29294-29314/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
01-25 07:46:05.818 29294-29294/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam D/android.widget.GridLayout: vertical constraints: y3-y0>=1047, y3-y2<=358, y2-y1<=358, y1-y0<=318 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y3-y2<=358. 

                                                                                                 [ 01-25 07:46:05.831 29294:29314 D/         ]
                                                                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa7ee4a00, tid 29314
01-25 07:46:05.832 29294-29314/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-25 07:46:05.832 29294-29314/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-25 07:46:05.832 29294-29314/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
01-25 07:46:05.832 29294-29314/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
01-25 07:46:05.835 29294-29314/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa7f050c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
01-25 07:46:05.870 29294-29314/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7f050c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7f030d0)
01-25 07:46:05.970 29294-29314/com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7f050c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7f030d0)


 **activity_main.xml and AndroidManifest.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/board" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.495">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="1"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="2"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="3"
          />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="4"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="6"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="7"
           />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="8"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:tag="9"
       />


    </GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="yenidenoyna"
        android:text="@string/sifirla"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gridLayout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    **AndroidManifest.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The app will post log in logcat if it fails. Post the logcat here.

Comment: Is this log when you work on emulator or on real phone?
And check the logging level in logcat.

Comment: Could you try to debug the app on some of the phones where it fails? Then post the result of the logcat here, if it's too long post it on pastebin and post the link here.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/n4kYRzAg
I try with lenovo k5 (it was stopped on this phone) and this is log

Comment: Could you try to remove `app:srcCompat="@drawable/board"`

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202156/8301966

Comment: Yeah, thank you  arcticwhite  man It's worked. But how can I put my board to my app?

Comment: @EmreSeyfi Is `board` an image or? Could you post it here?

Comment: I think all my Images ara causing the problem. (also board is image)

Comment: When I put a tictactoe X or O image also my app crashes.

Comment: @EmreSeyfi The problem can be if the image is too big. Check the image size, and try to resize it to make it lighter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was your error from [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/n4kYRzAg)...

```
    01 - 25 11: 37: 40.620 29867 - 29867 / ? E / AndroidRuntime : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam, PID: 29867
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {
        com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam / com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam.MainActivity
    }: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line # 0: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java: 633)
...
"com.sosisvesalam.kefelon.sossvesalam:drawable/board" (7f060053)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060053 a=-1 r=0x7f060053}
```

So the error was caused by the `board` image.
First of try removing the folowing line `app:srcCompat="@drawable/board"`

**Update 2:**
You sad your app fails when you add images, check the images size, if they are too big, try resizing them, just to make them lighter and/or smaller resolution.