# Binary XML runtime exception when trying to start activity

Tags: java

I'm trying to launch the application, but I get a `RuntimeException` stating that "RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ". Can someone help me?

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout splash_screen;
    WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        splash_screen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.africanshooting.com");
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        if (!isConnected())
        {
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Internet Connection")
                    .setMessage("Oups!il semblerait que vous n'etes pas connecter verifier vos parametres reseau")
                    .setPositiveButton("Fermer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).create();
                    alert.show();
        }

    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            splash_screen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            splash_screen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }  private boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo= connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

And here's the log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.africanshooting, PID: 25248
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.africanshooting/com.example.africanshooting.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1501)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5788)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.africanshooting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1501) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5788) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.africanshooting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1501) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5788) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.africanshooting-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.africanshooting-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.africanshooting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1501) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5788) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class) for similar stack trace. Likely you'll have to post your layout to get any joy.

Comment: its a simple problem of inflating xml. stack trace said enough, it cannot parse xml layout file, cause class, which it is trying to parse, doesnt exist.

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml-code of your activity layout (R.layout.activity_main) contains `android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout`. which doesnt exist in Android framework.

I guess you have smth like this in `activity_main.xml` file:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
```

Just change it with

```xml
<RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

change your root layout name from

OR change rootlayout to other layout which you want ,if u want to use realtive layout then just use

Answer (score 0):

Or add the dependency to your project. Add the dependency to your project in the build.gradle file.

Depending in which version you are using something like that:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
}
```