# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040007 a=-1}

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to run my Android Java application on a Android 9 tablet, (I have also tried a Android 13 phone), but it tells me it can't `resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040007 a=-1}`. 
Here is the full stack trace:

> 2023-05-15 13:17:26.799  4824-4824  AndroidRuntime          com...pp.formalsoftware.audioplayer  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.infinityfreeapp.formalsoftware.audioplayer, PID: 4824
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infinityfreeapp.formalsoftware.audioplayer/com.infinityfreeapp.formalsoftware.audioplayer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040007 a=-1}
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3093)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6865)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:504)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040007 a=-1}
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040007 a=-1}
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:775)
> at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7793)
> at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7984)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.(LinearLayout.java:1997)
> at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.(AppBarLayout.java:1280)
> at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.generateLayoutParams(AppBarLayout.java:707)
> at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.generateLayoutParams(AppBarLayout.java:141)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
> at com.infinityfreeapp.formalsoftware.audioplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8606)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8597)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1289)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2923)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3093)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6865)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:504)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Here's my `activity_main.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/nowPlayingTopAppBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nowPlayingTopAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="   Now Playing"
            app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar_for_now_playing"
            app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    <!-- ... -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And finally, my `MainActivity.java` file:

```java
package com.infinityfreeapp.formalsoftware.audioplayer;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.codekidlabs.storagechooser.StorageChooser;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton;
import com.infinityfreeapp.formalsoftware.audioplayer.Functions.Dialogs;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

The error seems to be suggesting that Android has an issue with the closing bracket of my `Toolbar`, which looks like this, when it's consolidated:

```java
        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nowPlayingTopAppBar"
            ...
            app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Isn't a closing `/>` fine?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class) and tried some of the suggestions, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it turns out that my application theme doesn't have a parent, hence the `?attr/actionBarSize` cannot be found.

Double check the theme you use for application or the activity. Its normally defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ...
    </application>
```

And in your `styles.xml` or `themes.xml`

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

Make sure AppTheme either has a parent or has all attributes you need defined.