# android-how to put the text below the image in grid view

Tags: android-gridview

in my application i want to display the text below the image in grid view.

The following is the code but it is not working. it shows an exception like this

```
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class linearlayout
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at sra.gri.vie.Main$ImageAdapter.getView(Main.java:63)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:932)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.linearlayout in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/sra.gri.vie-1.apk]
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     ... 26 more
05-31 17:23:32.017: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Process sra.gri.vie (pid 1262) has died.
```

**grid_item.xml**

```
<linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/GridItem"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:background="#000080">

 <imageview android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </imageview>

 <textview android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="TextView"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:textColor="#000000">
 </textview>

</linearlayout>
```

*main.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/gridview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

**Main.java**

```
 package sra.gri.vie;



   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.GridView;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

 public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View MyView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            //Inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

            // Add The Image!!!           
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

            // Add The Text!!!
            TextView tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
            tv.setText(names[position] );


        }
        return MyView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,

    };

   private String[] names={"Dog1","Dog2","Dog3","Dog4","Dog5","Dog6","Dog7","Dog8",}; 
}
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rename element `linearlayout` to `LinearLayout`.
I had the same issue and  fixed it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The error complains about the wrong package for linearlayout (android.view.linearlayout). The correct one is android.widget.LinearLayout. But I couldn't find any reference to linear layout in your code. It might help if you can paste the full exception stack trace.

Comment: 05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class linearlayout
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
05-31 17:19:29.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)

Comment: this doesn't help.. edit your question with the complete stactrace something similar to what is available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605999/android-how-to-track-down-the-origin-of-a-inflateexception

Comment: hi, i modified can you check it